# Octave: Why does the function "pause" not work when I use it in my code?

Tags: octave

I use the function "pause"(without parameter) in x.m, but It can not suspend the program. It just keep running when the program executed this function.

Comment: It's working as expected for me. Can you show a [mre] that reproduces the problem? How are you running your function, from the command line or in the GUI? What version of Octave are you using? What OS?

Comment: Plesse create a MCVE, explain what you expect to happen and what you see. And oft course please answer beakers questions

Comment: There are a few bugs related to pause that have been introduced since version 5.1 and seem that recently have been [fixed](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55943). As a workaround  instead of `pause` you can use `kbhit` .If it doesn't solve the problem you may need to switch to a previous version or wait for the next fixed version.

Comment: I had submitted this bug for 5.1.0 https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?55854

Answer (score 4):

`kbhit` didn't work for me. Using the `input` function helped me fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Octave 5.1 the pause function didn't pause the code as well. I am using it on Windows 10. The comment by rahnema1 did fix it for me. Just replace all your pause calls to kbhit and the problem is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

pause is disabled if the command:

```
pause off
```

is run.

If you run:

```
pause query
```

what is displayed?

You may need to run:

```
pause on
```

to make pause work again